# View/change IMAP/SMTP options in Outlook 365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, smtp

The interface of Outlook 365 has changed a few days ago with an update.

I can't find anymore where can I view or change the IMAP/SMTP options for the email accounts I've added to the application.

I'm trying to find a window similar to this:

[image: Change Account]

I'm not sure how it used to be before, but I can see in many places suggesting to go to File -> Account Settings. In the Window with the list of email accounts, I select the one I want, and then press "Change...".

Instead of seeing the Window I'm looking for, I see something like this:

[image: New Window]

This is really unhelpful. If I press "Next", I just see a success message saying that my account is set up. If I press "Reset Mail settings", absolutely nothing happens.

I want to see things like which ports are being used, and what's the "mail server", etc... and correct them, if needed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open Control Panel -> Mail, click 'Email Accounts' button. Then double click your IMAP account to see the settings.

Comment: wow... are they seriously doing this?! This is a real joke. They put a completely useless interface in the main UI, and we have to go through a "workaround", see the EXACT same "Account Settings" popup, and there, the "Change..." button works as expected... Thank you very much for your help.